# Change base URL for Wordpress for REST-API

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

Is there any possibility to change the base URL for WordPress Rest-API

```
The website URL is: Sitename.com

The Rest-API URL: Sitename.net/wp-json/...
```

So API request call from `.net`domain but the website is run from `.com` address.
But both address has the same WordPress engine.